How to Automate Exporting Google Docs to Markdown Using Google Apps Script?
I'm trying to automate the process of exporting Google Docs to Markdown format using Google Apps Script. I have noticed that when I go to a Google Doc, there are several export options available, including one for .md (Markdown) that works great. How can I automate this process?
Key Aspects of My Problem:

Native Export Options: Given that Google Docs provides an option to export documents as Markdown (.md), is there a way to automate this native export functionality using Google Apps Script?

Closest Solution I Found:
I read this Google Apps Script sample that generates a download link for one exact file, but it doesn't handle exporting many files at once.
Specific Question:

Native Export Options: Is there a way to automate the native .md export option in Google Docs using Google Apps Script for multiple documents in a folder?

Any guidance, examples, or insights on how to effectively automate this process would be greatly appreciated!
Update:
I just wanted to share an update that, with the help of Tanaike, I was able to create the tool I needed! This tool allows you to export any Google Drive folder while maintaining its subfolder structure and converting Google Docs to a specific file format (like Markdown or PDF). I've made the tool public so that others can benefit from it as well.
You can check out the tool here: Google Drive Folder Export & Google Docs Converter
A big thank you to Tanaike for the invaluable assistance and resources!

In your situation, is this post useful? Ref (Author: me) In this post, the sample scripts for converting Google Document to markdown format and vice versa are shown. When this script is used to Is there a way to automate the native .md export option in Google Docs using Google Apps Script for multiple documents in a folder?, how about the following sample script?
When you use this script, please enable Drive API at Advanced Google services. And, please set the values srcFolderId and dstFolderId.
Sample script 1:
In this script, Google Documents in a folder are converted to markdown format.
function sample1() {
  const srcFolderId = "###"; // Please set the folder ID of the folder including Google Documents.
  const dstFolderId = "###"; // Please set the destination folder ID.

  const token = ScriptApp.getOAuthToken();
  const dstFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(dstFolderId);
  const files = DriveApp.getFolderById(srcFolderId).getFilesByType(MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS);
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    const doc = files.next();
    const documentId = doc.getId();
    const url = `https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?exportFormat=markdown&id=${documentId}`;
    const res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { headers: { authorization: "Bearer " + token } });
    const blob = res.getBlob().setName(doc.getName() + ".md").setContentTypeFromExtension();
    dstFolder.createFile(blob);
  }
}

Sample script 2:
In this script, markdown files in a folder are converted to Google Documents.
function sample2() {
  const srcFolderId = "###"; // Please set the folder ID of the folder including Google Documents.
  const dstFolderId = "###"; // Please set the destination folder ID.

  const files = DriveApp.getFolderById(srcFolderId).searchFiles("(mimeType='text/markdown' or mimeType='text/x-markdown') and trashed=false");
  while (files.hasNext()) {
    const doc = files.next();
    const fileId = doc.getId();
    Drive.Files.copy({ name: doc.getName(), mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_DOCS, parents: [dstFolderId] }, fileId, { supportsAllDrives: true });
  }
}

Note:

In the current stage, it seems that when the markdown format is converted to Google Document, the images cannot be correctly shown. But, I believe that this will be resolved in the future update.

References:

Convert Google Document to Markdown and vice versa using Google Apps Script (Author: me)


Awesome post! Thank you so much for the references. I will read through them and make some minor tweaks to see if they work for my use case. I think they will. And sorry for the delayed response!

@Vladimirzb Did my answer show you the result that you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue as you can also base your question as a question that can be solved. If you have issues with my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Hi Tanaike,
Sorry for the delayed response! I just finished the tool I was working on and didn’t have an update until now that it worked!
Thank you so much for your help and the incredibly useful resources you provided. With your assistance, I was able to create the tool I needed, and I've made it public so that others can benefit from it as well. I've credited you for your invaluable help in the project. :)
Here is the repo: Google Drive Folder Export & Google Docs Converter
Thanks again!

@Vladimirzb Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.
